# UTF-8 setting issues when installing posix spawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, rubygems

I am experiencing a bunch of problems switching from `rvm`to `rbenv`. I had to reinstall `gem install posix-spawn`, but then I get:

> Successfully installed posix-spawn-0.3.6
>   Parsing documentation for posix-spawn-0.3.6
>   unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle

How can I make the conversion possible? I exported in my `.bash_profile` the variable `LC_CTYPE` and set it to `UTF-8`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try installing 'rdoc' gem.

```
gem install rdoc
```

Comment: I guess other people will have the same issue, thus it's better with explanation.